# How can I get iPhoneKeyboard.done if the keyboard is closed by native touch?

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, unity-game-engine

First of all, I found that different Android devices (or even iOS devices) will have their own handle when the native keyboard is on:

- In Galaxy Nexus, the keyboard will be dismissed by tap outside the keyboard
- In Sony Ericsson Acro HD, all responses behind is blocked until OK button on the keyboard is tapped.

I open the keyboard by `iPhoneKeyboard.Open()`. `iPhoneKeyboard.done` works fine if the OK button in the native keyboard is tapped. But the problem is `iPhoneKeyboard.done` is not triggered if it is dismissed by OS in Nexus.

How can I have `iPhoneKeyboard.done` in `true` if it is dismissed by OS?

Comment: Have you tried checking that they iPhoneKeyboard is not null?
if (keyboard != null)
if (keyboard.done == true)

Comment: Yes, I checked it.  Surprisingly, The problem in Nexus is solved after I upgrade my Unity from 3.5.2 to 3.5.6. I think Unity Team have solved the issue already. BTW, I will test on other device for more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading my Unity from 3.5.2 to 3.5.6. The problem in Nexus is solved. I think Unity Team have solved the issue already.
For reference, I found this in 3.5.6 fixes:
Android: Made sure OnScreenKeyboard can be opened again after being closed due to lost focus.